# Все ссылки в postman дают код 404 под uWSGI, в чём проблема?

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, postman

Использую связку django + django rest framework + nginx с виртуальным окружением. Найстройка nginx сделана вот [как тут в статье на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/226419/).

Проблема в следующем - если использовать стандартный сервер (командой `./manage.py runserver`), в postman все урлы и запросы работают корректно. При запуске uWSGI (`uwsgi --ini rest_api_uwsgi.ini`), все корректно работает только в браузере, в postman же на все урлы 404.

В консоли никаких сообщений, о том, что отправлены запросы нет, в логах ошибок тоже нет. В это же время такие же запросы прекрасно обрабатываются в браузере и в консоли видно, что было отправлено. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

На всякий случай вот конфиг

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

upstream django_rest {
    server unix:///public_html/rest_api/rest_api.sock; # взаимодействие с uwsgi через Unix-сокет 
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # взаимодействие с uwsgi через веб-порт
}

# конфигурация веб-сервера
server {
    # порт, который будет слушать веб-сервер в ожидании запросов от пользователй
    listen      8000;
    # доменное имя
    server_name     localhost; # замените на собственный домен или IP адрес
    charset     utf-8;

    # максимальный размер загружаемых на сервер данных
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    # обслуживание медиа файлов и статики
    location /media  {
        alias /public_html/rest_api/media;  # расположение медиафайлов (при необходимости измените)
    }

    location /static {
        alias /public_html/rest_api/static;  # расположение статики (при необходимости измените)
    }

    # Остальные запросы перенаправляются в Django приложение
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django_rest;
        include     /public_html/rest_api/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что показывает Postman? Если в браузере работает, то это не проблема в серверном окружении

Comment: Postman на все запросы отдает 404, не найдено. И на гет, и на пост, и на делит. В это же время гет из браузера работает. В постмане, если сервер nginx - при любом запросе 404. Если используется не nginx, а стандартный WSGI - все запросы отправляются и отрабатывают так, как нужно

Comment: В логах-то nginx видно чего-нибудь? Может быть Postman на какой-то другой сервер запросы отправляет.

Comment: нет, вообще ничего нет в логах из постмэна. отправляю на тот же адрес, что и в браузере localhost:8000. Я вот думаю, может в постмане какой-то особый способ отправлять запросы, какие-нибудь кроссдоменные или чего еще такое. Или может там для nginx нужны какие-то дополнительные параметры. Просто странно, что постмэн работает со стандартным сервером и вообще никакой реакции на nginx. Причем даже если отправлять запрос на прямую ссылку на какой-нибудь файл - localhost:8000/media/image.png. К слову, сначала работала в виртуальном окружении, потом поставила uWSGI глобально, бесполезно

Comment: да, и еще, попробовала аналоги постмэна, там при включенном nginx, такая же ситуация, все 404

Comment: А есть в nginx поменять порт на другой, пусть 8001, и постучаться на него из постмэна? Что будет в логах nginx? Ошибка 404 подписана nginx?

Comment: божечки, спасибо вам огромное. в аксесс лог, кстати, на 8001 порту: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2019:14:20:10 +0400] "GET /api/files/ HTTP/1.1" 200 643 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0", если обратно вернуть 8000:  ::1 - - [19/Mar/2019:14:21:50 +0400] "GET /api/files/ HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0" получается, проблема была в том, что 8000 порт был занят чем-то другим? ::1 - и вот эта конструкция что значит?)